# Cannot access local domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have setup a DNS server in a LAN. the BIND9 DNS server sits on 192.168.1.65

after setting my computer(macbook)'s dns server to 192.168.1.65, i am able to access the local domain setted up using bind, http://xyz.local/.

But when I access the url on the ubuntu server itself, it tells me that the url cannot be found. I can dig the link without problem, but the nslookup failed.

Any idea on how can I fix it so that the dns ubuntu box itself can also resolve the url?

Comment: What's in /etc/resolv.conf on the server? It is probably pointing to wrong dns server.

Comment: @rvs this is the content of /etc/resolv.conf: nameserver 192.168.1.65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be [mDNS/DNS-SD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDNS#Name_resolution).

The symptoms would be that name-resolution that goes through nss/libc fails (i.e. when you use applications like a browser, ping, etc.) but name-resolution with applications that query dns directly themselves (i.e. host, dig, etc.) succeeds in resolving the name.

If this is the case, on ubuntu you could try changing the hosts-entry in the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (remove `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]`) to say something like:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4
```

Comment: another problem is that the ubuntu keeps overwriting the dns ip in resolv.conf after reboot, how can i add 192.168.1.65 to it permly

Answer (score 1):

Point your server's dns to 127.0.0.1 (/etc/resolv.conf) and configure bind to forward the rest to your original isp dns-es.
Btw. Do you have reverse dns configured for your network addresses?

Comment: hi, yes i do have the reverse dns zone, the problem now is the other computer can access the local domains without problem, only the machine host the dns cannot resolve the domain, i also tried adding nameserver 127.0.0.1 to /etc/resolv.conf, but no luck..

Comment: do i need to restart the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restart the system, in order to flush any caches.
Also when you start nslookup and give the command server, what nameserver it writes.
Ex:

```
> server
Default server: 192.168.1.8
Address: 192.168.1.8#53
```

Comment: > server
Default server: 192.168.1.65
Address: 192.168.1.65#53